# How to ristrict Slave port's visiliblity when creating new AXI4 Slave port?

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I want to create an AXI4Slave port using `CanHaveSlaveAXI4Port` and `CanHaveSlaveAXI4PortModuleImp`. I was successfully able to create those. But now I want to restrict the port so it can only access the defined memory region. I know I can do that when I create a TileLink Slave port using `visibility` parameter in `TLClientParameters`. But I don't see any related variable in `AXI4MasterPortParameters`. I also took a look at `AXI4ToTLNode` which is where `TLClientPortParameters` parameters are evaluated from `AXI4MasterPortParameters` parameters and there is no relation of `visibility` defined there.
So is there any way I can restrict the AXI4 Slave port to access the defined memory region only? or add it to `dFn` in `AXI4ToTLNode`.